# c++, getting milliseconds since midnight in local time

Tags: c++, time, dst

It's unbelievable how difficult the above is to accomplish in C++. I'm looking for a way to do this as efficiently as possible while still maintaining millisecond precision.

The solutions I have so far have either required a lot of code and function calls making the implementation slow, or they require me to change the code twice a year to account for daylight savings time.

The computer this will be running on is synced using ntp and should have direct access to the local time adjusted for DST.  Can somebody with expertise on this share some solutions?

My platform is CentOS5, g++ 4.1.2, Boost 1.45, solution doesn't need to be portable, can be platform specific.  It just needs to be quick and avoid twice a year code changing.

Comment: What problem is being solved for you if you are able to obtain this information?

Comment: Why do you have to change the code twice a year to account for DST? What kind of false assumption are you depending on?

Comment: You say, "The solutions I have so far"...can you please list them?

Comment: Have you tried looking through [boost's libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.time_periods)? The link looks pretty relevant and short.

Comment: boost isn't useful here, i need to load a time zone spec csv file, that makes this call very slow and i really need this to be fast for the application it is for.

Comment: @user788171: Do you really need that kind of performance? If this is for the sake of keeping clock time, you don't need something that goes extremely fast. And if you need a fast time base, you would use the processor clock time, not the wall clock time anyway.

Comment: How do you want it to account for DST exactly? if the time is set back  do you want it to not subtract x number of microseconds?

Comment: So if you can solve the problem of what the current millisecond time is right now (easy) and at midnight then give you the difference but account for DST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers provided really does what I need it to do.  I've come up with something standalone that I think should work. If anybody spots any errors or can think of a faster method, please let me know.  Present code takes 15 microseconds to run.  I challenge SO to make something quicker (and I really hope SO succeeds =P)

```
inline int ms_since_midnight()
{
  //get high precision time
  timespec now;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&now);

  //get low precision local time
  time_t now_local = time(NULL);
  struct tm* lt = localtime(&now_local);

  //compute time shift utc->est
  int sec_local = lt->tm_hour*3600+lt->tm_min*60+lt->tm_sec;
  int sec_utc = static_cast<long>(now.tv_sec) % 86400;
  int diff_sec; //account for fact utc might be 1 day ahead
  if(sec_local<sec_utc) diff_sec = sec_utc-sec_local;
  else diff_sec = sec_utc+86400-sec_local;
  int diff_hour = (int)((double)diff_sec/3600.0+0.5); //round to nearest hour

  //adjust utc to est, round ns to ms, add
  return (sec_utc-(diff_hour*3600))*1000+(int)((static_cast<double>(now.tv_nsec)/1000000.0)+0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### C++20 update to new answer for old question

3<sup>*rd*</sup> party libraries no longer required.

Assuming one wants to measure "physical seconds".  I.e. if a daylight saving adjustment has been made since midnight, this computation takes that into account.  This code is very similar to the code below, but shortened to just the version that throws an exception if there is no local midnight, or if there are two local midnights.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::milliseconds
since_local_midnight(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t = std::chrono::system_clock::now(),
                     std::chrono::time_zone const* zone = std::chrono::current_zone())
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_time zt{zone, t};
    zt = floor<days>(zt.get_local_time());
    return floor<milliseconds>(t - zt.get_sys_time());
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << since_local_midnight() << '\n';
}
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jp0JS8JKNqlshZX2)

Explanation:

- Combine the `time_zone` and the `time_point` into a `zoned_time`.  A `zoned_time` is nothing more than a pairing of these two pieces of information.  It makes it convenient to retrieve either the local time, or the UTC (`sys`) time.
- Retrieve the local time and floor that to days precision to get the local midnight.  Assign this new local time back into the `zoned_time`.  This assignment will throw an exception if there is not a single midnight on this date in this time zone.
- Retrieve the UTC equivalent of the local midnight and subtract that from the input `time_point`.  Truncate the answer to milliseconds precision as requested in the OP.

See the more extended answer below for ways to deal with or work around the case where there are 0 or 2 local midnights.

### New answer for old question.

Rationale for new answer:  We have better tools now.

I'm assuming the desired result is "actual" milliseconds since the local midnight (getting the correct answer when there has been a UTC offset change since midnight).

A modern answer based on `<chrono>` and using this [free, open-source library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is very easy.  This library has been ported to VS-2013, VS-2015, clang/libc++, macOS, and linux/gcc.

In order to make the code testable, I'm going to enable an API to get the time since midnight (in milliseconds) from any `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` in any [IANA time zone](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

```
std::chrono::milliseconds
since_local_midnight(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t,
                     const date::time_zone* zone);
```

And then to get the current time since midnight in the local time zone is easy to write on top of this testable primitive:

```
inline
std::chrono::milliseconds
since_local_midnight()
{
    return since_local_midnight(std::chrono::system_clock::now(), 
                                date::current_zone());
}
```

Writing the meat of the matter is relatively straight-forward:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds
since_local_midnight(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t,
                     const date::time_zone* zone)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto zt = make_zoned(zone, t);
    zt = floor<days>(zt.get_local_time());
    return floor<milliseconds>(t - zt.get_sys_time());
}
```

The first thing to do is create a `zoned_time` which really does nothing at all but pair `zone` and `t`. This pairing is mainly just to make the syntax nicer.  It actually doesn't do any computation.

The next step is to get the local time associated with `t`. That is what `zt.get_local_time()` does. This will have whatever precision `t` has, unless `t` is coarser than seconds, in which case the local time will have a precision of seconds.

The call to `floor<days>` *truncates* the local time to a precision of `days`. This effectively creates a `local_time` equal to the local midnight. By assigning this `local_time` back to `zt`, we don't change the time zone of `zt` at all, but we change the `local_time` of `zt` to midnight (and thus change its `sys_time` as well).

We can get the corresponding `sys_time` out of `zt` with `zt.get_sys_time()`. This is the UTC time which corresponds to the local midnight. It is then an easy process to subtract this from the input `t` and truncate the results to the desired precision.

If the local midnight is non-existent, or ambiguous (there are two of them), this code will throw an exception derived from `std::exception` with a very informative `what()`.

The current time since the local midnight can be printed out with simply:

```
std::cout << since_local_midnight().count() << "ms\n";
```

To ensure that our function is working, it is worthwhile to output a few example dates. This is most easily done by specifying a time zone (I'll use "America/New_York"), and some local date/times where I know the right answer.  To facilitate nice syntax in the test, another `since_local_midnight` helps:

```
inline
std::chrono::milliseconds
since_local_midnight(const date::zoned_seconds& zt)
{
    return since_local_midnight(zt.get_sys_time(), zt.get_time_zone());
}
```

This simply extracts the `system_clock::time_point` and time zone from a `zoned_time` (with seconds precision), and forwards it on to our implementation.

```
auto zt = make_zoned(locate_zone("America/New_York"), local_days{jan/15/2016} + 3h);
std::cout << zt << " is "
          << since_local_midnight(zt).count() << "ms after midnight\n";
```

This is 3am in the middle of the Winter which outputs:

```
2016-01-15 03:00:00 EST is 10800000ms after midnight
```

and is correct (10800000ms == 3h).

I can run the test again just by assigning a new local time to `zt`. The following is 3am just after the "spring forward" daylight saving transition (2nd Sunday in March):

```
zt = local_days{sun[2]/mar/2016} + 3h;
std::cout << zt << " is "
          << since_local_midnight(zt).count() << "ms after midnight\n";
```

This outputs:

```
2016-03-13 03:00:00 EDT is 7200000ms after midnight
```

Because the local time from 2am to 3am was skipped, this correctly outputs 2 hours since midnight.

An example from the middle of Summer gets us back to 3 hours after midnight:

```
zt = local_days{jul/15/2016} + 3h;
std::cout << zt << " is "
          << since_local_midnight(zt).count() << "ms after midnight\n";

2016-07-15 03:00:00 EDT is 10800000ms after midnight
```

And finally an example just after the Fall transition from daylight saving back to standard gives us 4 hours:

```
zt = local_days{sun[1]/nov/2016} + 3h;
std::cout << zt << " is "
          << since_local_midnight(zt).count() << "ms after midnight\n";

2016-11-06 03:00:00 EST is 14400000ms after midnight
```

If you want, you can avoid an exception in the case that midnight is non-existent or ambiguous.  You have to decide before hand in the ambiguous case:  Do you want to measure from the first midnight or the second?

Here is how you would measure from the first:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds
since_local_midnight(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t,
                     const date::time_zone* zone)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto zt = make_zoned(zone, t);
    zt = make_zoned(zt.get_time_zone(), floor<days>(zt.get_local_time()),
                    choose::earliest);
    return floor<milliseconds>(t - zt.get_sys_time());
}
```

If you want to measure from the second midnight, use `choose::latest` instead.  If midnight is non-existent, you can use either `choose`, and it will measure from the single UTC time point that borders the local time gap that midnight is in.  This can all be very confusing, and that's why the default behavior is to just throw an exception with a very informative `what()`:

```
zt = make_zoned(locate_zone("America/Asuncion"), local_days{sun[1]/oct/2016} + 3h);
std::cout << zt << " is "
          << since_local_midnight(zt).count() << "ms after midnight\n";

what():
2016-10-02 00:00:00.000000 is in a gap between
2016-10-02 00:00:00 PYT and
2016-10-02 01:00:00 PYST which are both equivalent to
2016-10-02 04:00:00 UTC
```

If you use the `choose::earliest/latest` formula, instead of an exception with the above `what()`, you get:

```
2016-10-02 03:00:00 PYST is 7200000ms after midnight
```

If you want to do something *really* tricky like use `choose` for non-existent midnights, but throw an exception for ambiguous midnights, that too is possible:

```
auto zt = make_zoned(zone, t);
try
{
    zt = floor<days>(zt.get_local_time());
}
catch (const date::nonexistent_local_time&)
{
    zt = make_zoned(zt.get_time_zone(), floor<days>(zt.get_local_time()),
                    choose::latest);
}
return floor<milliseconds>(t - zt.get_sys_time());
```

Because hitting such a condition is truly rare (exceptional), the use of `try/catch` is justified.  However if you want to do it without throwing at all, there exists a low-level API within this library to achieve that.

Finally note that this long winded answer is really about 3 lines of code, and everything else is about testing, and taking care of rare exceptional cases.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on why you need "milliseconds since midnight" and what you plan to use it for.

Having said that, you need to take into account the fact that 3am doesn't really mean 3 hours since midnight, when DST is involved. If you really need "milliseconds since midnight" for some reason, you can get one Epoch time at midnight, another at 3am, and subtract the two.

But again, the notion of "midnight" may not be that stable in some cases; if a region's rule is to fall back from 1am to midnight when DST ends, you have two midnights within a day.

So I'm really doubtful of your dependence on "midnight". Typically, those broken-down times are for display and human understanding only, and all internal timekeeping is done with Epoch times.

Comment: the stock market opens at 930, the code needs to start at 930 sharp.

Comment: @user788171: For that, you only need to check that the broken-down time is 09:30:00, don't you? It's not even that the market opens 9 hours 30 minutes after midnight.

Comment: the incoming timestamps are milliseconds past midnight, millisecond accuracy+precision required to sync the code. gettimeofday and clock_gettime are the only options precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, `gettimeofday` gives the number of seconds/microseconds since the Epoch, which may help. But this really doesn't have anything to do with DST, since DST matters only with broken-down times (i.e. year, month, day, hour, minute, second).

To get the broken-down time, use `gmtime` or `localtime` with the "seconds" part of the result of `gettimeofday`:

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
struct tm *t = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);  // t points to a statically allocated struct
```

`localtime` gives the broken-down time in your local timezone, but it may be susceptible to DST. `gmtime` gives the broken-down time in UTC, which is immune to DST.

Comment: So this is the heart of the problem.  The output of gettimeofday is not in my local time.  To convert to my local time, I need to know the current difference between UTC and EST, but this changes twice a year.  If I extract this difference by also looking up the local time and comparing with the UTC time from gettimeofday, this is an extra call that slows down the function by quite a bit.

Comment: @user788171: Do you really need that kind of performance? If this is for the sake of keeping clock time, you don't need something that goes extremely fast.

Comment: it's not only that. if i were to do it the way i described (e.g. using gettimeofday and localtime together), there are rare, but possible instances where between two hours, i get a different result for the difference between UTC and local.

Comment: @user788171: It's possible, very obviously, that you are in UTC-0400 at 1am and UTC-0300 at 3am during the same day. But it's very natural, and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Is the fact that your function call is already a bit slow and therefore giving out a millisecond value that is a little bit old indicative that you don't really that kind of precision afterall?  why can't it be accurate to 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `localtime_r`, and `mktime` after adjusting the result of `localtime_r` to compute the value of "midnight" relative to the Epoch.

**Edit:** Pass `now` into the routine to avoid an unnecessary call to `time`.

```
time_t global_midnight;
bool checked_2am;

void update_global_midnight (time_t now, bool dst_check) {
    struct tm tmv;
    localtime_r(&now, &tmv);
    tmv.tm_sec = tmv.tm_min = tmv.tm_hour = 0;
    global_midnight = mktime(&tmv);
    checked_2am = dst_check || (now >= (global_midnight + 2*3600));
}
```

Assume `global_midnight` is initially `0`. Then, you would adjust it's value at 2am, and the next day, so that it stays in sync with DST. When you call `clock_gettime`, you can compute the difference against `global_midnight`.

**Edit:** Since the OP wants to benchmark the routine, tweaking code for compilers that assume `true` to be the fast path, and round to nearest msec.

```
unsigned msecs_since_midnight () {
    struct timespec tsv;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsv);
    bool within_a_day = (tsv.tv_sec < (global_midnight + 24*3600));
    if (within_a_day)
        if (checked_2am || (tsv.tv_sec < (global_midnight + 2*3600))
            return ((tsv.tv_sec - global_midnight)*1000
                    + (tsv.tv_nsec + 500000)/1000000);
    update_global_midnight(tsv.tv_sec, within_a_day);
    return ((tsv.tv_sec - global_midnight)*1000
            + (tsv.tv_nsec + 500000)/1000000);
}
```

Comment: @user788171: `time` is only used to compute `midnight in terms of EPOCH seconds`. `clock_gettime` to get the high resolution time and the compute difference with `midnight`.

Comment: @user788171: I have upated the answer. Regards

Comment: this could work, i may eventually switch to something like this, but in the meantime i have posted another solution that i like better because it is one function and easier to use.

Comment: @user788171: I don't think there is anyway your code can beat the fast path for my solution. If `global_midnight` is initialized before this routine runs, this routine only consists of a call to `clock_gettime` and some simple integer math. Your routine will always call `localtime` as well, and do floating point math on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to the post [here] and made a change so that the below function can return the milliseconds since midnight in GMT time.

```
int GetMsSinceMidnightGmt(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tpNow) {
    time_t tnow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tpNow);
    tm * tmDate = std::localtime(&tnow);
    int gmtoff = tmDate->tm_gmtoff;
    std::chrono::duration<int> durTimezone(gmtoff); // 28800 for HKT
    // because mktime assumes local timezone, we shift the time now to GMT, then fid mid
    time_t tmid = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tpNow-durTimezone);
    tm * tmMid = std::localtime(&tmid);
    tmMid->tm_hour = 0;
    tmMid->tm_min = 0;
    tmMid->tm_sec = 0;
    auto tpMid = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(tmMid));
    auto durSince = tpNow - durTimezone - tpMid;
    auto durMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(durSince);
    return durMs.count();
}
```

If you want to have local time, it is much more easier.